# How many Hamiltonian cycles are there in $K_{10,10}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, trees, hamiltonian-path

I want to calculate the number of Hamiltonian cycles in $K_{10,10}.$
Could anyone help me? I think in $K_{10}$ we have $9!$ Hamiltonian
cycles.

Comment: I think in $K_{10}$ we have $9!/2$ Hamiltonian cycles. Tell me, how many Hamiltonian cycles do you have in $K_3$?

Comment: @bof, i have no idea :)

Comment: You think you know the answer for $K_{10}$ but you have no idea about $K_3$?

Comment: @bof, i search on google.

Answer (score 0):

For all n≥3, the number of distinct Hamilton cycles in the complete graph K<sub>n</sub> is (n−1)!/2.

So for K<sub>10</sub>, 9!/2

Comment: The question is about the complete bipartite graph $K_{10,10}$, not the complete graph $K_{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about complete *bipartite* graphs? If yes, then please look [here](http://oeis.org/A143248).

Comment: would u please add more detail ?

Comment: General formula for the number of (directed) Hamiltonian cycles for $K_{n,n}$ is $n!(n-1)!$